# Minimization of a integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, optimization

$g$ is a function and has compact support. We may assume for some constant $R>0$ that $g=0$ on $\mathcal{R}\cap\{|x|\geq R\}$. Let $h(x)=\int_0^xg(y)\,dy$. Therefore, 
\begin{equation}
h(x)=\begin{cases}
h_\_ \quad \text{if } x \leq -R, \\
h_+ \quad \text{if } x \geq R,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
for constants $h_{+}, h_\_$. 
Let $p:=-2\min\limits_{x\in \mathcal{R}}\int_{-\infty}^xg\,dy,\,$ $q:=2\max\limits_{x\in \mathcal{R}}\int^{+\infty}_xg\,dy$.

Then, how to prove
$$\min_{\mathcal{R}}h=-\frac{p}{2}+h_\_=-\frac{q}{2}+h_+?$$

Comment: I guess this is part of the proof of Theorem 6 in Chapter 3.4 of the PDE book by L. C. Evans. Am I right? In that case, the integral for q goes from $x$ to $+\infty$.

Comment: @AugSB   Yes. Do u know how to prove it?

Comment: @AugSB I post another question about the detail of the proof of Theorem 6 on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191227/questions-about-a-detail-in-the-proof-of-theorem-6-in-chapter-3-4-of-evans-pde. Could u also have a look at it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\int_0^xg(y)dy = \int_{0}^Rg(y)dy-\int_x^Rg(y)dy = h_+-\int_x^Rg(y)dy.$$

Plug that into $\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\int_0^xg(y)dy $ and use that for any constant $c$ and function $f$, $$\min(c-f(x)) = c-\max(f).$$

I hope you can complete the proof with those hints.