# Questions about a detail in the proof of Theorem 6 in Chapter 3.4 of Evans PDE

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have a problem with the details of the proof of Theorem 6 in Chapter 3.4 of Evans PDE.

In page 162, the author has the following statements:

> Owing to Theorem 5, we have $|u|=O(t^{1/2})$ and by definition $|N|=O(t^{-1/2})$. In addition (71) implies $((1\pm\epsilon)t)^{1/2}-t^{1/2}=O(1)$. Using these bounds along with (72), (73) and (78), we estimate
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|u(x,t)-N(x,t)|dx=O\left(t^{-1/2}\right)."$$

How to get the estimation by using these bounds?

**Background:**
The following are formulas mentioned in the above statements.

$$(71) \quad \quad \quad \epsilon=\epsilon(t)=\frac{A}{t^{1/2}}\quad(t>0),$$
$A$ is a constant.

We claim that if $A$ is sufficiently large, then
$$(72) \quad \quad \quad u(x,t)=0 \quad \text{for} \quad x-\sigma t<-R-(pd(1+\epsilon)t)^{1/2},$$
and
$$(73) \quad \quad \quad u(x,t)=0 \quad \text{for} \quad x-\sigma t>R+(qd(1+\epsilon)t)^{1/2}.$$
For large t, we have
\begin{equation}
(78)\quad\quad\quad\begin{cases}
|u(x,t)-\frac{1}{d}\left(\frac{x}{t}-\sigma\right)|\leq \frac{C}{t} \, \text{if}\\
R-(pd(1-\epsilon)t)^{1/2}<x-\sigma t<-R+(qd(1-\epsilon)t)^{1/2}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$p,q,d$ are constants and $p\geq 0, q\geq 0, d>0$. $N(x,t)$ is a N-wave. Given constants $p,q,d,\sigma, $with $p\geq 0, q\geq 0, d>0$, we define the corresponding N-wave to be the function
\begin{equation}N(x,t)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{d}\left(\frac{x}{t}-\sigma\right) \, \text{if} \, -(pdt)^{1/2}<x-\sigma t<(qdt)^{1/2}\\ 0 \quad\quad \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}\end{equation}
The constant $\sigma$ is the velocity of the N-wave.

$u(x,t)$ is the solution of the scalar conservation law: 
\begin{equation}\begin{cases}u_t+F(u)_x=0 \quad\quad\text{in}\,\mathcal{R}\times(0,\infty)\\ u=g \quad\quad\text{on}\, \mathcal{R}\times\{t=0\}.\end{cases}\end{equation}
The explicit formula of $u(x,t)$ is given by the Lax-Oleynik formula.

Comment: @William Thanks for your edit. I think Theorem 5 is not important. It's conclusion is just $|u|=O(t^{1/2})$.